# How can I find angle alpha in terms of a and l?

Tags: geometry

I know a and l, and that the dotted lines are parallel, how can i determine the angle alpha in terms of a and l?
I've been working on it non-stop for the past two days and I can't find a solution, although my system seems fully constrained.
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX8DM.jpg)

Comment: Please Include what did you try in last two days,To get An idea of your line of thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your figure breaks down into an isosceles trapezoid and a right triangle.

Lets say $\gamma = \arctan \frac {2a}{l}$

That is the angle of the right triangle that is next to $\alpha$.
We can then go angle chasing.  The complementary angle in the right triangle is $90-\gamma$ and that is supplementary to one of the angles of the trapezoid $90+\gamma$

Now we have $\gamma + 90+\gamma + \alpha = 180^\circ$

$\alpha = 90-2\gamma$